# Magento 2: Using Email Template as PDF Print template for Invoice, Shipment and Credit Memo

Tags: templates, pdf-generation, magento2, invoice

I am trying to change the default template of the PDF generated by the Print Button to make it the same as my custom email template in Magento 2.
[image]

Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2

Comment: Hi Jon. I tried using that but it only applies to the invoice pdf. I need to customize the shipment and credit memo print pdf too. Thanks though. :)

Comment: in the video it looked like it did all of them?